# Snail Sort - Stuck in the middle, not sure how to proceed

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am stuck at this place, where, I couldn't proceed further. The question goes like this. Given an `n x n` array, return the array elements arranged from outermost elements to the middle element, traveling clockwise.

```
array = [[1,2,3],
         [4,5,6],
         [7,8,9]]
snail(array) #=> [1,2,3,6,9,8,7,4,5]
```

For better understanding, please follow the numbers of the next array consecutively:

```
array = [[1,2,3],
         [8,9,4],
         [7,6,5]]
snail(array) #=> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

This image will illustrate things more clearly:

[image]

The attempt I have got so far is:

```
arr = [[1, 2, 3], [3, 4]];
var n = arr[0].length;
var i = 0, j = 0;
var fa = [];
var count = 0;
var direction = "right";
console.log(n);
while (fa.length < n * n) {
    fa.push(`${i}, ${j}`);
    if (j == n - 1 && i < n - 1) {
        direction = "down";
    } else if (j == 0 && i != 0) {
        direction = "up";
    } else if (i == n - 1) {
        direction = "left";
    } else if (i == 0) {
        direction = "right";
    }
    switch (direction) {
        case "right":
            j++;
            break;
        case "left":
            j--;
            break;
        case "up":
            i--;
            break;
        case "down":
            i++;
            break;
    }
    if (count++ == 15)
        break;
}
console.log(fa);
```

I am kind of not sure how to proceed. I need to know two things.

1. How should I proceed from here?
2. What is the mistake I am making?

Comment: You should show/describe the output you are getting from your code, so we have an idea of what is wrong...

Comment: Every time you change direction you should remove/avoid the row/column you just finished.  This would work very well recursively.

Comment: @SunilD. Boss, I have given my full code, what else do you expect? Instructions for you: http://i.imgur.com/nc29mXa.png

Comment: @nurdyguy Yes! I am doing it with a mapping. So the `i` and `j` value get incremented and decremented for the limits. I am doing it but, not sure where I go wrong.

Comment: Showing the code is key, but it also helps to describe what the code is doing. In this case, show us what is being logged to the console.  Or if you're getting an error, tell us what the error is.

Comment: @SunilD. I guess you are in a completely different universe. I don't know what to tell you yet! The image I have provided shows everything you want.

Comment: @SunilD. I guess you are in a completely different universe. I don't know what to tell you yet! The image I have provided shows everything you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I did for this problem.  You can see how I am keeping track of the min and max col and row values as we go.  I'm not sure exactly how you were doing that in your code but hopefully this helps.

```
var m = 4;
var n = 4;
var board = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [5, 6, 7, 8],
    [9, 10, 11, 12],
    [13, 14, 15, 16]
];

var result = [];
var dir = 'right';
var imin = 0;
var imax = m - 1;
var jmin = 0;
var jmax = n - 1

var i = imin;
var j = jmin;
var done = false;

while (!done)
{

    switch (dir)
    {
        case 'right':                
            i = imin;
            j = jmin;
            for (j; j <= jmax; j++)
                result.push(board[i][j]);
            console.log(result);
            dir = 'down';
            imin++;
            break;
        case 'left':
            i = imax;
            j = jmax;                
            for (j; j >= jmin; j--)
                result.push(board[i][j]);
            console.log(result);
            dir = 'up';
            imax--;
            break;
        case 'down':
            i = imin;
            j = jmax;
            for (i; i <= imax; i++)
                result.push(board[i][j]);
            console.log(result);
            dir = 'left';
            jmax--;
            break;
        case 'up':
            i = imax;
            j = jmin;
            for (i; i >= imin; i--)
                result.push(board[i][j]);
            console.log(result);
            dir = 'right';
            jmin++;
            break;
    }

    if (imin > imax || jmin > jmax)
        done = true;
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Wow. This is like perfect! Thanks! I did the same thing, didn't I? Where did I go wrong?

Comment: From what I can tell yours is basically going to go in a circle around the outside.  Once you finish a side you need to remove that side so you don't keep following it.  I did this by setting `imax` `imin` `jmax` and `jmin`.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for being this late.

My solution to the problem is

```js
arr = [
 [1,2,3,4],
 [5,6,7,8],
 [9,10,11,12],
 [13,14,15,16],
];


function rotate(arr) {
 copy = [];

 rows = arr.length;
 for(i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
  cols = arr[i].length;
  for(j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
   if(copy[cols - 1 - j] === undefined) copy[cols - 1 - j] = [];
   copy[cols - 1 - j][i] = arr[i][j];
  }
 }

 return copy;
}

res = [];
do {
 res = res.concat(arr.shift());
 arr = rotate(arr);
} while(arr.length);

console.log(res);
```